# C and C++ for Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, linux

As I write Java application, I no need to worry much on the execution in Linux and Windows environment.  For the C and C++, is there any tools or techniques that I can apply?

Comment: Depends significantly on what kind of code you're trying to write; care to narrow this down a bit? e.g., Apache modules vs Desktop GUI applications will of course be different...

Comment: I've seen some apps package a cygwin dll and run fine on windows.  Not sure the details but its someting to look into.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend QT: http://qt.nokia.com/products/

It is not only an excellent cross-platform GUI library, but has cross-platform libraries for many other common needs -- such as networking.

Not to mention it has its own beautiful IDE.

Comment: I will work on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For writing cross-platform code in C++, there are two main techniques typically taken in parallel:

1. Write Standard-Compliant code.  By definition, any C++ code that you write that both conforms to the Standard and doesn't use any platform-specific libraries is cross-platform.  All conformat C++ compilers must be able to compile it.  However, this won't get you all the way there, because there are many things you just can't do with the Standard Library alone.  So...
2. Use a cross-platform library, such as Boost.  The code you write that uses Boost (or another cross platform library) is itself cross-platform.  The implementation details of Boost itself often are not.  But if your goal is to be able to write one set of code that works on both Windows and Linux, you can use Boost to do it.